# How to see what's changed on git

Tags: git, remote, diff

A bunch of new commits have been made on the remote git repository, and you want to see what's changed from the version you have checked out on your computer previously. How do you do so?

Answer (score 3):

Simple. First run `git fetch` to get all the commits on the repo without making any local changes. Then, if your branch is called 'web' for example, run (assuming your remote is called origin)

```
git diff web..origin/web
```

or

```
git difftool web..origin/web
```

if you want to see the changes in a GUI.

If you want to only check what's changed in one file, you can specify the path to the file

```
git diff web..origin/web path/within/repo/to/file.py
```

This should be straightforward to find on Google, but surprisingly wasn't. Putting in the specific commit SHAs is effort and somehow didn't work for me.